# Login username and password for one user small edit required

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

Firstly, l am very new to creating html and php codes in websites, so if this may seem a trivial question to some on here please appreciate that l require a bit of help. Thanks

I have created a login username and password form for just one user (html form) to work in conjunction to a .php code, it works perfectly.

Current:

1. It will not allow the form to submit if either username and/or
   password fileds are blank.
2. incorrect username and/or password
       displays the echo ("incorrect"); text on the www.......com/login.php
       page.
3. When both username and password filed are entered
           correctly it redirects to the required page.

EDIT WANTED:

1. Instead of the displaying the echo ("incorrect"); text on the
   www.......com/login.php page. I want "incorrect" to to be displayed
   underneath or within the html form. This saves going back to the
   original page each time to redo the entries.

Thank you.

HTML FORM:

```
  <fieldset>

        <legend>Login</legend>

        <label for="username" >UserName: </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="true" />

        <label for="pass" >Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required="true"/>

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
         <include'login.php'/>
     </fieldset>

</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php

       if(($_POST['username'] == "user1") && ($_POST['pass'] == "pass1"))

    { 

     header("Location:http://www.yahoo.com");

    }


    else


    {
      echo ("incorrect");

    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the form inside the else condition then the login is handled in a single file

```
<?php
     if(($_POST['username'] == "user1") && ($_POST['pass'] == "pass1"))
  { 
    header("Location:http://www.yahoo.com");
  }
 else
 { ?>

<form name= "login" method="post" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <label for="username" >UserName: </label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="true" />
    <label for="pass" >Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required="true"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
     <include'login.php'/>
 </fieldset>
</form>

<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        echo "incorrect";
      }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, can l insert this directly into the <div> .......</div> section of my html page?

Comment: or do l keep the form as it is in the html (as shown above in my original code) and just make the amendments and re-upload the .php file

Comment: What you are asking is imposible, you want to display the string `'incorrect'` if the login failed, thats php output which you cannot put into an html file. You must place this code inside the index and rename from .html to .php

Comment: note that I removed the action from the form, now it will submit to itself

Comment: Thanks @andrew, this works, for displaying the incorrect, but when both user and pass are filled in correctly it just removes the login box completely on the page and does not redirect to the page website specified in the header condition. How would l resolve this? I have saved and done the changes exactly as you have asked up to this point. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I don't know why, I just tested this locally and it works. Try pasting the above into a new php file with no other content and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
{
echo "incorrent";
}
```

type:

```
{
header("Location: loginform.php?error=incorrect");
}
```

and in your login form .php something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo $_GET['error'];
}
```

Or even better: you could save your form as a .php . And start the form with

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

do you post logic.

then display the form.

and in the input vars, type

```
<INPUT value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] :''; ?>">
```

EDIT:
To summarize:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST)) {

     if(check) { 
        header("Location ...);
     } else { 
       $error = 'incorrect';
     }

} else {
   $error = '';
}
?>   
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<fieldset>

    <legend>Login</legend>

    <label for="username" >UserName: </label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username] : ''; ?>" id="username" name="username" required="true" />
    <label for="pass" >Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required="true"/>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>

 </form>
 <?php echo $error; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, What do l need to add to the html form part?

Comment: So your post action url is your form itself. This way the POST data can be displayed in your form.

Comment: Unfortunatley due to the way l have written the entire page in html l would not be able to save the form type as .php

Comment: If you could include your edit in what l have put above that would help a lot for me. Thank you, all this language is still very new to me

Comment: No problem. Just rename the .html to .php. Your server will interpret <?php ?> as PHP in your HTML. This way you can add the PHP code in your Html and have the Html created dynamically, based on your $_POST vars.

Comment: Thanks, so the top part <?php to ?> l save as my .php file which is not publicly visible>
And the second part from <form action to <?php echo $error; ?> i insert into my html div? Am l correct? Thank you

Comment: You could save all of it in one file. The form will point to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], then the file that also contains the form will pickup the $_POST vars. The php code will never be visible because it is rendered before it is transferred to the client. .php files are usually accessible, it is the php code in the file that is rendered by php into HTML if applicable, so you you wont see any code. We say <?php echo $error; ?> and the client sees the value of $error.